# Erro ao iniciar CWP CentoOS + Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, certificado-digital

Pessoal eu uso o CWP para administrar meus dominios onde coloco meus sistemas em PHP, acontece que hoje criando um subdominio o servidor gerou um erro, acho que algum bug, e não consigo mais iniciar o Apache nem o CWP, a mensagem no log do CWP é essa:

> 2018/01/02 17:09:39 [emerg] 8032#0: PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("/etc/pki/tls/certs/hostname.crt") failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)

Eu tive que mudar o hostname da maquina, imagino que deva ser por isso que gerou o erro, tentei voltar o hostname anterior mas sem chance.

Comment: pq não utilizar cloudflare?

Comment: Ja uso o CWP a um bom tempo e nunca tive problema, precisei fazer uma alteração que me gerou um erro e estou quebrando a cabeça, e esse cloudflare nao conhecia, mas agora pra mudar todo meu servidor vai ser complicado